# How can I automatically convert all source code files in a folder (recursively) to a single PDF with syntax highlighting?

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, html

I would like to convert source code of a few projects to one printable file to save on a usb and print out easily later. How can I do that?

### Edit

First off I want to clarify that I only want to print the non-hidden files and directories(so no contents of `.git` e.g.).

To get a **list of all non-hidden files in non-hidden directories in the current directory** you can run the `find . -type f ! -regex ".*/\..*" ! -name ".*"` command as seen as the answer in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/601222/how-to-print-out-all-non-hidden-files-recursively-in-a-dir-using-lpr).

As suggested in that same thread I tried making a pdf file of the files by using the command `find . -type f ! -regex ".*/\..*" ! -name ".*" ! -empty -print0 | xargs -0 a2ps -1 --delegate no -P pdf` but unfortunately the **resulting pdf file is a complete mess**.

Comment: Don't know if it fits your need, but with `a2ps -P file *.src` you can produce postscript files out of your source code. But the PS files need to be converted and combined afterwards.

Comment: Using convert (http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_convert.htm, imagemagick) you should then be able to make one pdf from the ps files.

Comment: Can you comment, what you mean with "complete mess"? This (http://i.stack.imgur.com/LoRhv.png) looks not too bad to me, using `a2ps -1 --delegate=0 -l 100 --line-numbers=5 -P pdf` -- I added `-l` for 100 chars per row to prevent some word wraps and line numbers, but that's only personal preference.

Comment: For converting [this](https://github.com/dhgamache/Cinderblock) project(4 non-empty non-hidden files each about a page long in non-hidden directories) to pdf I had about 5 pages of source code and 39 pages of gibberish.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I was intrigued by your question and got kinda carried away. This solution will generate a nice PDF file with a clickable index and color highlighted code. It will find all files in the current directory and subdirectories and create a section in the PDF file for each of them (see the notes below for how to make your find command more specific).

It requires that you have the following installed (the install instructions are for Debian-based systems but these should be available in your distribution's repositories):

- [`pdflatex`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdflatex), [`color`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/) and [`listings`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings)

  ```
    sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra latex-xcolor texlive-latex-recommended
  ```

This should also install a basic LaTeX system if you don't have one installed.

Once these are installed, use this script to create a LaTeX document with your source code. The trick is using the [`listings`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) (part of `texlive-latex-recommended`) and [`color`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/) (installed by `latex-xcolor`) LaTeX packages. The `\usepackage[..]{hyperref}` is what makes the listings in the table of contents clickable links.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tex_file=$(mktemp) ## Random temp file name

cat<<EOF >$tex_file   ## Print the tex file header
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}  %% Allow color names
\lstdefinestyle{customasm}{
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=C++,   %% Change this to whatever you write in
  breaklines=true, %% Wrap long lines
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{Gray},
  stringstyle=\color{Black},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{OliveGreen},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  xleftmargin=-8em,
}        
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

EOF

find . -type f ! -regex ".*/\..*" ! -name ".*" ! -name "*~" ! -name 'src2pdf'|
sed 's/^\..//' |                 ## Change ./foo/bar.src to foo/bar.src

while read  i; do                ## Loop through each file
    name=${i//_/\\_}             ## escape underscores
    echo "\newpage" >> $tex_file   ## start each section on a new page
    echo "\section{$name}" >> $tex_file  ## Create a section for each filename

   ## This command will include the file in the PDF
    echo "\lstinputlisting[style=customasm]{$i}" >>$tex_file
done &&
echo "\end{document}" >> $tex_file &&
pdflatex $tex_file -output-directory . && 
pdflatex $tex_file -output-directory .  ## This needs to be run twice 
                                           ## for the TOC to be generated
```

Run the script in the directory that contains the source files

```
bash src2pdf
```

That will create a file called `all.pdf` in the current directory. I tried this with a couple of random source files I found on my system (specifically, two files from the source of `vlc-2.0.0`) and this is a screenshot of the first two pages of the resulting PDF:

[image]

---

A couple of comments:

- The script will not work if your source code file names contain spaces. Since we are talking about source code, I will assume they don't.
- I added `! -name "*~"` to avoid backup files.
- I recommend you use a more specific `find` command to find your files though, otherwise any random file will be included in the PDF. If your files all have specific extensions (`.c` and `.h` for example), you should replace the `find` in the script with something like this

  ```
    find . -name "*\.c" -o -name "\.h" | sed 's/^\..//' |
  ```
- Play around with the `listings` [options](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings), you can tweak this to be exactly as you want it.

Comment: Wow, that's what I call an answer! `:)`

Comment: OMG terdon, you owned that question ^^. To other people trying the script: if you run into `src2pdf: line 36: warning: here-document at line 5 delimited by end-of-file (wanted EOF')` when running the script you have to [delete the whitespace on the EOF line](http://www.krenger.ch/blog/bash-here-document-at-line-n-delimited-by-end-of-file-wanted-eof/) in order for it to work.

Comment: The script `src2pdf` also adds the contents of the script to the pdf, any idea how I can omit that?

Comment: If your file is called `src2pdf` then insert `! -name "src2pdf"` in the `find` line in the script like this `find . -type f ! -regex ".*/\..*" ! -name "src2pdf" ! -name ".*" ! -name "*~" |` to omit it in the pdf.

Comment: @Bentley4 thanks! I removed the whitespace (it was added whern I pasted the script into the answer) and added the filter to remove the script itself from the `find` results (I had saved the script in another directory that was in my $PATH so I did not have that problem). Also, you can change the language used for the source files to have better markup by changing `language=C++` to whatever you want, it can deal with many different languages, see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings#Supported_languages).

Comment: Wow, nice. Didn't notice that before, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Awesome! But how would I handle UTF8? Adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to the header doesn't make it possible to process a Lua 5.2 file with German language (äöüÄÖÜß) comments in  `UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators` file.

Comment: @qubodup I don't really know. LaTeX and UTF8 can be tricky. It _should_ work with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} `\usepackage[german]{babel}` but it fails on my tests. However, I suspect I'm not feeding it true utf8. That might be worth its own question but I suggest you ask on [tex.se], they should know.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for checking! I was lucky enough to find a solution thanks to multiple questions and answers (links inside), I'm now using http://codepad.org/7iLVB8Se which gives me pages that look like http://i.imgur.com/lGaYcAi.png

Comment: Underscores in file names throw off the PDF since underscore means subscript to Latex.  I modified the \section{$i} to use sanitized input:

`while read i; do                ## Loop through each file`
`name=${i//_/\\_}`
`echo "\newpage" >> $tex_file   ## start each section on a new page`
`echo "\section{$name}" >> $tex_file  ## Create a section for each file`

Comment: @MattLiberty oh, good catch! I edited that in, thanks!

Comment: Hey there! I just noticed that there is an article with stuff that looks pretty similar to this if you want to investigate: https://samhobbs.co.uk/2017/01/bash-script-generate-pdf-source-code-syntax-highlighting-using-latex.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 thanks for the heads up, but the author of the article links back to this post in their code, so everything's fine. Nice when the system works :)

Comment: Ah! I didn't check the code :D Cheers for checking and the response!

Comment: Thanks a lot! The line `echo "\section{$i}" >> $tex_file` should be `echo "\section{$name}" >> $tex_file`.

Comment: I have a lot of binary files mixed in my tree, so I found modifying [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678132/238405) (see my comment) with `! -exec grep -Il . "{}" \;` at the end to be very helpful

Comment: There's a typo in the script where it has `\section{$i}` when it's supposed to be `\section{$name}`. With that typo in place, underscores aren't sanitized correctly.

Comment: Good catch, @jjramsey, thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm waaaay too late, but somebody looking for a solution might find this useful.

Based on @terdon's answer, I have created a BASH script that does the job: https://github.com/eljuanchosf/source-code-to-pdf

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 2):

(from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917413/cat-multiple-files-but-include-filename-as-headers))

```
for i in *.src; do echo "$i"; echo "---"; cat "$i"; echo ; done > result.txt
```

This will result a result.txt containing:

- Filename
- separator (---)
- Content of .src file
- Repeat from the top until all *.src files are done

If your source code have different extension, just change as needed. You can also edit the echo bit to add necessary information (maybe echo "filename $1" or change the separator, or add an end-of-file separator).

the link have other methods, so use whatever method you like best. I find this one to be most flexible, although it does come with a slight learning curve.

The code will run perfectly from a bash terminal (just tested on a VirtualBox Ubuntu)

If you don't care about filename and just care about content of files merged together:

```
cat *.src > result.txt
```

will work perfectly fine.

Another method suggested was:

```
grep "" *.src > result.txt
```

Which will prefix every single line with the filename, which can be good for some people, personally I find it too much information, hence why my first suggestion is the for loop above.

Credit to those in the StackOverflow forum people.

EDIT: 
I just realized that you are after specifically HTML or PDF as the end result, some solutions I've seen is to print the text file into PostScript and then convert postscript to PDF.
Some code I've seen:

```
groff -Tps result.txt > res.ps
```

then

```
ps2pdf res.ps res.pdf
```

(Requires you to have ghostscript)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This only works for files of a specific extension(.src) but I want every file to be put in that pdf regardless of extension. I do would like to omit non-hidden dirs and non-hidden files though. I edited the original post, could you take a look at it?