# How can I save only selected part of web page with Google Chrome?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, html

I would like to save web pages as PDFs ([see this question](https://superuser.com/questions/612570/how-can-i-convert-html-to-pdf)) but I don't know how to save only the selected (highlighted) part of the web page, so I only save for example an article, not the whole page. Every browser saves the whole page from `File->Save page as...`

Comment: what about Selecting area and the Right Clicking and click on Inspect Element? Select the container with the data you want (table or div etc...) and then you can "Copy as HTML"  into a doc and then output the doc to pdf

Comment: This is not bad idea at all, but this way I lose every (CSS) formatting and need to much clicking :D to achieve a simple task.
Also you can only select one block at a time and digging into the HTML this much doesn't worth it.

Comment: None of the current answers really retain proper formatting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open the webpage in chrome
2. Select the desire portion
3. right click > print [Dont press Ctrl+P]
4. save as PDF

Comment: In Firefox, just select the desired portion and press Ctrl-P. Click on "Selection" in Range and Print to file, Save output as PDF.

Comment: Works the same way in Vivaldi: right click > Print

Answer (score 1):

I use evernote web clipper plugin for chrome for this purpose. You can either clip pages as notes or PDF as well.

Answer (score 1):

These methods do not work if you select certain area on the web page using the mouse. Then only the section visible in the browser without scrolling

Comment: is there a solution to print selection beyond the visible area?

Answer (score 0):

HTTrack website copier is capable of doing this, but you'd have to download the whole site.  After, though, you could import it into Adobe Dreamweaver and edit to your hearts content!